# Can "I am taken care of by her" be rewritten as "I am taken care by her" ?

Tags: grammaticality, passive-voice, light-verbs

> "I am taken care of by her."

The above sentence has two prepositions: "of" and "by".

For me to learn English, using both "of" and "by" simultaneously is very hard to understand.

Are these necessary for grammar in the sentence?

Is the following incorrect:

> "I am taken care by her."

Comment: I'm pretty sure this should be on ELL, though I can't do anything about closing it right now.

Comment: Your question raises a number of issues that are probably address in English Language Learners,  ell.stockexchange.com    To answer your immediate question, "I am taken care by her" should be "I am taken care of by her," although that sentence sounds awkward.  "She takes care of me" is probably how most people would write.  Good luck, and welcome to stackexchange.

Answer (score 4):

No, you absolutely need that *of* there. Otherwise the expression sounds incomplete. The base form is *to take care of something or someone*. *of* must be there because it's part of the phraseological structure of the expression! This is the same thing as leaving out *up* in *to be fed up with something* or leaving out *am* in *I am a man*. It sounds incomplete, broken and just grammatically wrong. End of discussion.

Example:

> I am going to **take care of it**.
>   **It** is going to **be taken care of** by me.